# How can I sell pallid sturgeon?

Tags: far-cry-5

My friend and I went fishing and caught a bunch of pallid sturgeon which is rated as "hard". We went to the nearest shop to sell them but didn't see them available.

How can we sell them or do something with them?

Comment: I found selling prices for fish and animals but nothing on where to sell at.  I would recommend you try a different shop.  https://www.reddit.com/r/farcry/comments/883ioi/all_fish_and_animals_selling_prices/

Comment: Is your problem limited to Pallid Sturgeon, or can you not sell **any** kind of fish?  What about animal skins?  What happens if you try again?  Also, what platform are you playing on?

Comment: @dg99 i havent tried all the fish hut i know ive been able to sell others and able to sell animal skins. Xbox one.

Comment: I have also tried again

Comment: Are you in the middle of a mission that requires you to catch Pallid Sturgeon?

Comment: @dg99 nope. No active missions. Simply explored a bunch with a friend and found a cool fishing spot

Answer (score 1):

That sounds like a glitch - you should be able to sell the fish you've caught.

Since you were playing in co-op it's possible that the game bugged and didn't register your friend's catch. This is more likely if he isn't the host since that may generate a more tenuous internet connection. If your friend were the host then it would be less likely, but not improbable.

Your friend may have quick sold the all the items in their inventory and not realized that *also* sold the fish. The quick sell button from the shop's menu includes everything except for collectibles and items used in crafting. Fish falls into neither category so if your friend wasn't paying attention he may have unwittingly sold their catch.

In this situation I'd recommend catching another fish and seeing if the problem persists. I would expect this to be a one-time occurrence.